# How to get text element of the given react component in React.cloneElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, locale, globalization

Developers give me the headings of the table:

```
const CustomersTable = () => {

    var headers=<>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Another text</th>
    </>

    return <Table
               headers={headers}
           />
}
```

And this is the code of the `Table` component:

```
const Table = ({headers}) => {

    var clonedHeaders = React.Children
            .toArray(headers.props.children)
            .map(header => React.cloneElement(header, {
                className: "text-gray-900 py-3 font-light text-xs"
            }));

    return <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
                {clonedHeaders}
            </tr>
         </thead>
    </table>
}
```

I can use `React.cloneElement` to add attributes to the elements I receive as props of my component.

However, I want to be able to change the text content of those received elements too.

For example, I want to call my **locale translation function** on table header elements, **automatically**. Right now, if developers want to make their tables multi-lingual, they should write this:

```
var headers = <>
    <th>{t('Name')}</th>
    <th>{t('Age')}</th>
    <th>{t('Other text')}</th>
</>
```

I want to centralize that `t(text)` function for all `headers` prop. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same technique on the child elements of the headers as you do on the headers themselves:

```
const clonedHeaders = React.Children
        .toArray(headers.props.children)
        .map(header => React.cloneElement(header, {
            className: "text-gray-900 py-3 font-light text-xs",
            children: React.Children.toArray(header.props.children).map(child => {
                return typeof child === "string" ? t(child) : child;
            })
        }));
```

Live Example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

function t(english) {
    // Just so we can see that it happens
    return english.toLocaleUpperCase();
}

const CustomersTable = () => {

    var headers=<React.Fragment>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Another text</th>
    </React.Fragment>;

    return <Table
               headers={headers}
           />;
};

const Table = ({headers}) => {

    const clonedHeaders = React.Children
            .toArray(headers.props.children)
            .map(header => React.cloneElement(header, {
                className: "text-gray-900 py-3 font-light text-xs",
                children: React.Children.toArray(header.props.children).map(child => {
                    return typeof child === "string" ? t(child) : child;
                })
            }));

    return <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
                {clonedHeaders}
            </tr>
         </thead>
    </table>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<CustomersTable />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

That example doesn't do any recursion, so it won't handle `<th><span className="something">Name</span></th>`. If you want to handle that, you'll have to write a recursive function to handle it, but it'll be along the same lines.

Comment: This was one of the most pleasant answers I've seen in my life. Easy and very practical. I managed to globalize the headers of more than 100 tables in 5 minutes, instead of weeks. Thank you so much.